# How to update a dbSet if the record has changed in the database?

Tags: entity-framework

If I detect that a record in the database has been changed by another process and the record is a member of my current dbSet, how do I update that record to reflect the data of the changed database record? As I understand it Attach will fail if the item is already present.

I use a large subset of the data in-memory to update status on the screen and allow users to change the data. Other processes do the same.

I am using EF7 (core) which is probably not that smart as I am new to EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Load() method to rehydrate the affected entity from database:

Just in case, first do get your entity detached

```
DbContext.Entry(changed).State = EntityState.Detached;
DbContext.MyDbSet.Where(e => e.Id == changed.Id).Load();
```

Above, *Load()* will get the entry again into the set.

Before you can use it, you will need to import  **Microsoft.Data.Entity** namespace

Comment: Why detach first? I realised the depth of my misunderstanding of EF and bought 2 books, so no necessity to respond - hopefully I can educate myself!

Comment: No strict necessity to detach first, it could be just me but, as EF is still RC I prefer to protect my self.